# Xwindows on Red Hat linux

Tags: linux, redhat

We have leased a Redhat linux server to install database..

We want to start a graphical user interface

When I type xclock

-bash: xclock]: command not found

What are the libraries which needs to be installed..

I looked into /usr/X11R6/bin but it contains only two files mkfontdir & mkfontscale and none with X...

Could you please advise ?

Answer (score 2):

If your system is entitled to Red Hat support (or if it's a CentOS machine), just

`yum install xorg-x11-apps`.

other usefull yum(1) commands:

`yum provides '*/xclock'`

`yum grouplist`

`yum groupinstall 'X Window System'`

Answer (score 1):

We did this to our Oracle servers and what a complete pain.  We did it to keep all of those processes from sucking down server memory.  Well, every installation requires a nice handful of X11 libraries in order to kick off the installer.  Yes, starting an application to a remote display still requires a large collection of relevant libraries be available.  Our stripped down version was so stripped that getting an application installer to start is a royal pain.  All it accomplished was making my DBA mad at me.

My advice is this: let Redhat install all of the X11 apps, libraries, even Gnome if you want.  Then just shut them down.  Disable them with `chkconfig`, notably `gdm` or `xdm` as it is sometimes called.  You may need to shut down the font server as well (`xfs` I think).  The installers will be able to find all of their happy libraries to display to a remote box.  Addtionally, if you ever need to run the tools from the console, you can just `service start gdm` and go from there.  When you're done, log out and shut the `gdm` service off.

That said, don't let it install a bunch of stupid stuff like Evolution, Empathy, calculators, etc.  You may even elect to ditch Gnome and only put on a lightweight window manager.  This simplifies what you have to install.  Using the Server version will keep these and other things like `bluez` (Bluetooth) to a minimum, but you should look through your kickstart to see what else you can safely remove.

One last thing.  The best tool for testing an X11 connection is `xdpyinfo` as it a) doesn't provide a stupid popup and b) you could script it into regular commands that require a valid X11 connection before allowing the script to continue.

Answer (score 0):

Running `ldd` against the approriate binaries will tell you which libraries are missing, and then from there you can install them with yum.